# CSS fill elements into grid (and center them)

Tags: html, css

I want a data-grid (table layout) with elements that have a fixed size. The elements should be inserted into the same line as long as they can and then they should appear in the next line.

I can do that with inline-blocks but then I don't know how to control the outer div to center them.

Here is my problem:

[probnlem http://images.devs-on.net/Image/QUPPczp4bO6pkKNR-Bereich.png](http://images.devs-on.net/Image/QUPPczp4bO6pkKNR-Bereich.png)

Do you have any ideas how to solve this with using just CSS?

Comment: is your container fixed size as well?

Comment: Of course not, because I don't know its size.

Comment: then it would be a little harder.

Comment: there is two way to go.wrap you elements with an inner container and center that container.2- going absolute position way(which will require some computation).

Comment: Can you explain that to me please? I don't understand your first idea.

Comment: i will provide a jsfiddle.one moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your blocks are set on inline-block dispay, you just have to center the text of your container : http://jsfiddle.net/Qv6xY/20/ (resize the result pannel)

html :

```
<section>
    <article>a</article>
    <article>a</article>
    <article>a</article>
    <article>a</article>
    <article>a</article>
    <article>a</article>
    <article>a</article>
    <article>a</article>
    <article>a</article>
</section>​
```

css :

```
section{margin:50px; padding:25px; background:#333; text-align:center;}
article{width:50px; height:50px; background:#c00; margin: 10px; display:inline-block}
```

(Or there's something more you want to do that I did not get.)

Comment: Thats working pretty cool do you think its possible to align the elements to the left? For example if all rows have 3 elements and the last row has just 2 elements they are centered but the should be aligned to the left

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a way to do "full-justification" on the boxes within the space. There is not a way to accomplish this with pure CSS at this time. You will need to choose between what you already have, which ends up with space on the right, or what @fabien provided which leaves your last line centered.

The alternative is to use some javascript.

(PS As long as you only want the letter "a" in those boxes, there might be another solution, but I'm assuming that is a placeholder for more complex elements. Correct?)

Comment: Yes that is true. I think I will use a bit of javascript then. Thanks